# Windows 8: Bing map holding event doesnt work for PC mouse, but works fine in touch mode

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps

today i meet a new problem with Bing Map on Metro, holding event doesn't work for mouse but when i change it to touch mode it works fine. Help me please!!!

```
<Bing:Map x:Name="bingMap" Credentials="{StaticResource BingCredentials}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          Width="700" Height="600" IsHoldingEnabled="True" Holding="Bing_Holding"  />


private async void Bing_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e){
        try
        {
            await new MessageDialog("I'm superman!").ShowAsync();
        }
        catch{}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made some research about your question and find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding).

It explain that the Holding event can't work with mouse generally. There are a few tips too that explain wwhy this event don't work and with why you should replace it.

I recommend you to read this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387#using_manipulation_events) too. Its a quickstart guide for the Touch Input.

Hope it can help you.